# How can I pass date/text to <input type="date">?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set text in input date but nothing shows there.
Is it something wrong with data type?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="invoice">
        2020-09-22
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    

<select id="decisionList">
  <option></option>
  <option>Payment date</option>
</select>

<div id="choice">
</div>



<script>

document.addEventListener("change", function () {

  var decisionList = document.getElementById("decisionList");
  var selectedOptionIndex = decisionList.options[decisionList.selectedIndex].index;  
  
  var invoiceDate = document.getElementById("invoice");
  var invoiceDateText = invoiceDate.textContent;
  
  var finalChoice = document.getElementById("choice");

  switch(selectedOptionIndex) {
    
    case 0:
        finalChoice.innerHTML='<input type="date">'
    break;
   
    case 1:
        finalChoice.innerHTML='<input type="date" value="' + invoiceDateText + '">' //here is a problem
    break;

    default:
    
    finalChoice.innerHTML=''
    
  }
  
})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to create new Date based on text I'm passing:

```
  var newDate = new Date(invoiceDateText);
```

but also doesn't work. As you can see I'm passing 2020-09-22 (from td) so where is the problem?

Comment: Please could you clarify? What is happening and what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: WHen I'm passing ```invoiceDateText``` to date input then nothing shows up, no date. Nothing. I want to show there date from here: ```<td id="invoice">
        2020-09-22
        </td>```

Comment: I answered you back beneath your answer

Comment: I noticed, that when I change code for  ```case 1:
        finalChoice.innerHTML='<input type="date" value="' + "2020-09-11" + '"> 
    break;``` then it works properly. But when I pass ```invoiceDateText``` then it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable invoiceDateText contains white spaces and therefore is not parsed correctly.

You can update that part to the following.

```
 var invoiceDateText = invoiceDate.textContent.trim();
```

Comment: I have one more issue with this code: datepicker doesn't work. I choose a date and it can't be chosen. I also can't change date ona datepicker. Why is that happening?

Comment: You event listener is on the document, which is why when the datepicker changes it runs again and the same value is set again. So instead you can change the event listener to listen on decisonList.

var decisionList = document.getElementById("decisionList");

decisionList.addEventListener("change", function () {

Answer (score 1):

The date should be a string and formatted by **YYYY-MM-DD**

Comment: but it is in this format, look at <td id="invoice">
        2020-09-22
        </td>